# Array is not working as expected(error in accessing specific value) Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
console.log(LoadingIcons)
console.log('LoadingIcons' + LoadingIcons[i])
```

This is the code I am using

[image]

Comment: what the value of `i`?

Comment: what is the value of i here?

Comment: i is the index.

Comment: here its 0.....